# how to load .jar dynamically to apk using frida

Tags: dynamic, frida

I'm going to load .jar dynamically to apk and call a certain method of a class in that jar. Using frida, I've tried to load jar file but failed.

```
Java.perform(function(){
    var pathclassloader= Java.use('dalvik.system.PathClassLoader');
    var myClassLoader = pathclassloader.$new("/Sdcard/testjar.jar", classloader.getSystemClassLoader());

    const Class=Java.use('java.lang.Class');
    var forName = Class.forName.overload('java.lang.String', 'boolean', 'java.lang.ClassLoader');

    forName.call('client', true, myClassLoader);

})
```

it failed with error :

> {'type': 'error', 'description': "ReferenceError: identifier 'classloader' undefined", 'stack': "ReferenceError: identifier 'classloader' undefined\n    at [anon] (../../../frida-gum/bindings/gumjs/duktape.c:81019)\n    at /script1.js:6\n    at frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/vm.js:11\n    at E (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:346)\n    at frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:298\n    at frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/vm.js:11\n    at frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:278\n    at /script1.js:15", 'fileName': '/script1.js', 'lineNumber': 6, 'columnNumber': 1}

Any help for me. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us where you are defining `classloader` for the `classloader.getSystemClassLoader()` call?

Comment: Java.perform(function(){
 console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>load jar start');

 var classloader=Java.use('java.lang');
 var pathclassloader= Java.use('dalvik.system.PathClassLoader');
 var myClassLoader = pathclassloader.$new("/Sdcard/testjar.jar", classloader.getSystemClassLoader());

 const Class=Java.use('java.lang.Class');
 var forName = Class.forName.overload('java.lang.String', 'boolean', 'java.lang.ClassLoader');
 
 forName.call('client');
 
 
 console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>load jar end');
})

Comment: Please don't put code in comments (total unreadable). Edit your question instead.